# Preload for css file used directly

Tags: html, css, optimization, browser, preload

It's a naive question but i'm wondering if there is a gain to use preload link for a css file requested directly

```
<head>
  <link rel=preload href=/style.css as=style>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=/style.css>
</head>
```

Instead of a classic

```
<head>
  <link href=/style.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>
```

Comment: There would not be any gain in that particular example namely in preloading an element that will be downloaded later on in the document anyway as the CSS file would be downloaded - and *presumably* cached - if it's loaded with a regular `<link href=/style.css rel=stylesheet>` link therefor nulling any future use for the preload link. There are better uses for preload such as adding it in the footer of **page A** to preload **page B**  when you know that there is a very high chance that users tend to go to **page B** right after visiting **page A**